# SQL IFNULL on SELECT * statement

Tags: mysql, sql, ifnull

Is there a way to set a default value for all returned values that are null, specifically in MySql?

Instead of

```
SELECT 
  IFNULL(foo, 0),
  IFNULL(bar, 0),
  IFNULL(baz, 0)
FROM table
```

I would like to do something like:

```
SELECT IFNULL(*, 0)
FROM table

// this does not work, but I'm looking for something like it
```

Comment: No, there isn't a way to do this in SQL.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, and for anyone else that comes upon this post, the reason I cannot place an IFNULL on each item is due to the fact that I'm dynamically generating the SQL in an ORM style, so I know neither the number of columns, or data types of those columns being returned, but I then LEFT JOIN against another table (a table of days, for example) and do a select * from the dynamic table.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A result of a function in SQL is a single value (column), not a list of columns. So there isn't, and can't be, such a construct. You'd have to handle every column individually, unfortunately.

Comment: Not the answer I was hoping for, but certainly good to know for sure.

Answer (score 0):

You could add default values to the table if you don't care about preserving `NULL`:

```
ALTER TABLE yourTable ALTER foo SET DEFAULT 0;
```

You could also create a view where you write out each of the `IFNULL()` statements once and just use that to save from re-typing it all the time.

But as others indicated, no construct to do it simply like you hoped.

You can also quickly do repetitive things like this using table metadata:

```
SELECT CONCAT("IFNULL(",`COLUMN_NAME`,",0)")
FROM `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`COLUMNS` 
WHERE `TABLE_SCHEMA`='yourdatabasename' 
    AND `TABLE_NAME`='yourtablename';
```

Comment: Unfortunately many of the values in my select are calculated values, and there are some tables where I do want nulls in the table, but just not in the report being generated.

Answer (score -1):

You can try case statement for sql as below

```
    select 
CASE 
  WHEN foo is null THEN 0  else foo end

  from urtable
```

and then same for other columns